# IAsyncEnumerator could not be found; System.Interactive.Async NuGet package not working on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been developing a .NET project with OSX for some time, and just opened it for the first time on Windows 10. Upon attempting to compile, I receive the error:

`IAsyncStreamReader.cs(53, 46): [CS0246] The type or namespace name 'IAsyncEnumerator<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

*edit* this dependency comes from `System.Interactive.Async`, which is resolved by NuGet to version `3.1.1`. The JetBrains Rider IDE shows no errors or problems with this dependency, and [the NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) lists its only dependency as .NET 4.5. Pressing `Go To -> Declaration` on `IAsyncEnumerator` successfully decompiles the .dll in Rider.

My project:

- **TargetFramework**: `.NETFramework v4.5`
- **Output type**: `Class library`
- **Language**: `C# 7.0`
- **References/Assemblies**: (*all appear resolvable, managed by NuGet*): `Google.Protobuf`, `Google.ProtocolBuffers`, `Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization`, `GraphQL-Parser`, `Microsoft.CSharp`, `MySql.Data`, `Newtonsoft.Json`, `System`, `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, `System.Data`, `System.Interactive.Async`, `System.Reactive.Core`, `System.Reactive.Interfaces`, `System.Reactive.Linq`.

Comment: Make sure you have using System, using System.Collections, using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: what namespace do you expect it to be in? im not finding any learn.microsoft.com reference to it

Comment: also i'm confused why you are trying .net framework 4.5 when it wasn't a framework project to begin with - is it a .net core or mono assembly?

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.iasyncenumerator-1?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: @GSerg yea - that didn't seem related.

Comment: When I `Go To -> Declaration` in Rider, it points to `System.Collections.Generic`, de-compiled from `System.Interactive.Async` (which, as mentioned, resolves correctly) at `packages\System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1\lib\net46\System.Interactive.Async.dll`. Curiously, I note that it references `net46` (not `net45`?) and wonder if that's related.

Comment: @DanielA.White to your question about frameworks, I apologize in that I'm still unpacking how this works... but, the DLL I generate is used within Unity (game development tool), and I believe (?) it's Mono, in that it successfully compiles for all targets including Windows, OSX, iOS, Android, Linux, etc.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, that's the package. Apologies for the confusion with .NET core. Still, the dependency resolves correctly at the project level and is shown at version 3.1.1 by NuGet, and meets the `.NET Framework 4.5` dependency. I'm very confused, then, why it's failing to compile only on Windows.